# Ruby method with parameters in double parenthesis

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters

I have come across the following code in erb library. Note the double `(( ))`:

```
class MyTest
  def location=((filename, lineno))
    @filename = filename
    @lineno = lineno if lineno
  end
end
```

The following `locatia=` method is another version without the `(( ))` for testing:

```
class MyTest    
  def locatia=(filename, lineno)
    @filename = filename
    @lineno = lineno if lineno
  end
end
```

I got this result:

```
a = MyTest.new
a.location = "foo", 34
a # => #<MyTest:0x2a2e428 @filename="foo", @lineno=34>

b = MyTest.new
b.location = "foo"
b # => #<MyTest:0x2a2e338 @filename="foo">

c = MyTest.new
c.locatia = "foo", 34
c # >> `locatia=': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

The version with double parenthesis works fine. The one with single fails. It must be specified on some level of the source code. Any clues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Destructuring.

`location=` accepts one parameter. This parameter is assumed to be an array, and is destructured so that the first element of array goes into `filename`, and the second into `lineno`. The outer parentheses are the normal (usually optional) parentheses of a method definition; the inner parentheses indicate the structure of the first (and only) parameter.

Here's another example of destructuring at work:

```
{ foo: 17, bar: 34 }.each.with_index { |(key, value), index|
  p [key, value, index]
}
# => [:foo, 17, 0]
#    [:bar, 34, 1]
```

`Hash#each` generates pairs `[key, value]`; `Enumerator#with_index` generates pairs of `[value, index]`. Apply them both, and you get `[[key, value], index]` passed to the block. We could just do this:

```
{ foo: 17, bar: 34 }.each.with_index { |pair, index|
  key = pair[0]
  value = pair[1]
  p [key, value, index]
}
```

but it is so much simpler with destructuring. We could even write `(key, value) = pair` (or `key, value = pair`, as single-rvalue arrays are automatically destructured in multi-lvalue assignment) as another example of destructuring.

Comment: It's referred to in Ruby docs as [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition),

Answer (score 8):

It's a little unusual to see this in production code, but what's happening here is *list expansion* in an argument list:

```
def location=((filename, lineno))
end
```

What this means is you call it this way:

```
x.location = 1,2
```

Where those get *expanded* into two separate arguments. A mutator method can only take one argument, but that argument can be a list and you can expand that argument into multiple values.

Normally you see this in iterators like:

```
{ a: 'b', c: 'd' }.each_with_index.map do |(k,v), i|
  # k, v come in as a pair, i is separate
end
```

Though even then it's pretty rare.

You can also see it in other cases:

```
a = [ 1, 2 ]
b = 3

# Without list expansion, just one-to-one assignment
x, y, z = a, b
# x => [ 1, 2 ]
# y => 3
# z => nil

# With list expansion
(x, y), z = a, b
# x => 1
# y => 2
# z => 3
```